# pandas dataframe: How to replace a value in a row, based on whether the ID of that row is in a certain list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I’ve got this dataset(df) that includes Unique IDs representing a person, then certain IDs for jobs each person has applied for that go across a row like so

| ID | JobA | JobB | JobC | JobD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 31 | 56 | 67 |
| 2 | 4 | 13 | 31 | 43 |
| 3 | 7 | 18 | 31 | 33 |
| 4 | 31 | 34 | 52 | 58 |

Now I want to delete/replace the 31 JobID with NaN, based on whether a persons ID is in a specific list let's say list = [2, 4] so it looks like this:

| ID | JobA | JobB | JobC | JobD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 31 | 56 | 67 |
| 2 | 4 | 13 | NaN | 43 |
| 3 | 7 | 18 | 31 | 33 |
| 4 | NaN | 34 | 52 | 58 |

How do I approach this?
I've tried

```
df.loc[df['ID].isin(list)].replace(31, np.nan)
```

However, it doesn't seem to permanently change df.
Any help is greatly appreciated, and sorry if this question isn't formatted well, it's my first post!

Comment: try ```df = df.loc[df['ID].isin(lista)].replace(31, np.nan)``` if the operation you performed already produces the necessary output, I believe it is enough to store the copy in the variable that is working

Answer (score 0):

One option using a boolean mask:

```
lst = [2, 4] 
mask = df['ID'].isin(lst)
df[mask] = df[mask].replace(31, float('nan'))
```

output:

```
    ID  JobA  JobB  JobC  JobD
0  1.0  23.0  31.0  56.0  67.0
1  2.0   4.0  13.0   NaN  43.0
2  3.0   7.0  18.0  31.0  33.0
3  4.0   NaN  34.0  52.0  58.0
```

Or, if you do not want to alter the original DataFrame:

```
lst = [2, 4] 
mask = df['ID'].isin(lst).to_numpy()[:,None] # to 2D for broadcasting
df2 = df.mask(df.eq(31)&mask)
```

output:

```
   ID  JobA  JobB  JobC  JobD
0   1  23.0    31  56.0    67
1   2   4.0    13   NaN    43
2   3   7.0    18  31.0    33
3   4   NaN    34  52.0    58
```